# Windows Installer Bundle

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, installshield

Ok so I got past my initial issue where the Installation was failing. I apologize for the lack of information. Basically my question now is. Is it possible to pass chained .msi packages command line options like /x, etc... I have 2 MSI packages I am executing as part of my install. The first must always attempt to uninstall itself.

[chained .msi package properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIRWD.png)

Would the "install properties" be the place to place these parameters? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: "It fails" is quite vague; do verbose logs have more details on what error you encounter? Have you tried using the Suite project type (if you have the Premier edition)? It's in its infancy in IS2012, but is typically more robust than the chained .msi packages support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by?:

> but my problem is that it fails unless I actually deploy something with the actual original "bundle" setup

You don't want those MSI's included in the wrapper/suite/bundle package?

Advanced Installer and Wix Toolset also have support for bundles. Here is a tutorial for Advanced Installer [suite installations](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html).